# binary I/O between python and C

Tags: python, c

I'm trying to convert binary files written in C to and from HDF5 files using Python.
To read the binary file Python works like this:

```
pos=np.fromfile(f, count=npt*3, dtype='f4').reshape((npt, 3))
```

To write the same thing I've tried, without success, array.tofile() and now I'm tryin to     use ctypes like that (stitching together different answers found on the web):

```
import ctypes as c

print "Loading C libraries with ctype"
libc = c.CDLL("libc.so.6") # Linux

# fopen()
libc.fopen.restype = c.c_void_p
def errcheck(res, func, args):
    if not res: raise IOError
    return res

libc.fopen.errcheck = errcheck
# errcheck() could be similarly defined for `fwrite`, `fclose` 

c_int_p = c.POINTER(c.c_int)
c_float_p = c.POINTER(c.c_float)
c_double_p = c.POINTER(c.c_double)


def c_write(data, f, numpy_type, c_type_p, nbyte, count):
    data = data.astype(numpy_type)
    data_p = data.ctypes.data_as(c_type_p)
    nitems  = libc.fwrite(data_p, nbyte, count, f)
    if nitems != data.size: # not all data were written
        print "Not all data were written, exit..."
        sys.exit()


c_write(pos, f, np.int32, c_int_p, 4, npart.size)
```

Answer (score 3):

You should probably look into the `struct` module, it's awesome for packing and unpacking data at the lowest byte-per-byte level.